# Megacli is killing me, any help appreciated

Tags: raid

I run a server with 2 drives in raid0 configured through BIOS. I just added 2 more drives using hotplug (the server is dell r610 with RHEL  5.4 64bit) and I would like to configure a separate raid0 partition on these drives. I am getting the following error:

> /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -CfgLdAdd r0[32:2, 32:3] -a0
>
> The specified physical disk does not have the appropriate attributes to complete
>   the requested command.
>
> Exit Code: 0x26

All the parameters are correct and there is just no reason why this command could not work, see this (fujitsu is current raid, seagate is the new one I want to create):

```
/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -PDList -aALL | egrep 'Adapter|Enclosure|Slot|Inquiry'
Adapter #0
Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 0
Enclosure position: 0
Inquiry Data: FUJITSU MBD2147RC       D807D0A4PA101174
Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 1
Enclosure position: 0
Inquiry Data: FUJITSU MBD2147RC       D807D0A4PA10115T
Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 2
Enclosure position: 0
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE ST9300603SS     FS033SE0TF5K
Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 3
Enclosure position: 0
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE ST9300603SS     FS023SE070FK
```

I also tried to set up the drive as hotspare, also some strange error:

> /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -PDHSP -Set -physdrv[32:3] -a0
>
> Adapter: 0: Set Physical Drive at EnclId-32 SlotId-3 as Hot Spare Failed.
>
> FW error description:
>    The specified device is in a state that doesn't support the requested command.
>
> Exit Code: 0x32

As you can see the disk is in Unconfigured, Good state:

```
Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 3
Enclosure position: 0
Device Id: 3
Sequence Number: 1
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS
Raw Size: 279.396 GB [0x22ecb25c Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 278.896 GB [0x22dcb25c Sectors]
Coerced Size: 278.875 GB [0x22dc0000 Sectors]
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c50005cd20b1
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 3(path0)
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE ST9300603SS     FS023SE070FK
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: Foreign
Foreign Secure: Drive is not secured by a foreign lock key
Device Speed: Unknown
Link Speed: Unknown
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :30C (86.00 F)
```

Answer (score 17):

The drive is marked as "Foreign", it probably comes from some other RAID controller. I guess you may need to clear it first :

`MegaCli64 -CfgForeign -Scan -Clear`

Comment: for a short moment I though you are correct, I even found a comment on google saying that "drives with foreign state are  not usable in a new controller until that state is removed", also the drives I am trying to use were previous used in another server!!! however there seems the new controller doesn't find any foreign configuration, see below:

    /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -CfgForeign -Scan -a0
    There is no foreign configuration on controller 0.

ps. why is the formatting which worked during "answer a question" not working in comments?

Comment: also /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -CfgForeign -Clear -aALL

There is no foreign configuration on controller 0.

Comment: I moved these drives to another server (non production) and this cleared the foreign state!!! moved drives back to production server, the foreign state is still cleared, now trying to create raid on these drives :)

Comment: yes creating the raid worked now :) thanks for the clue!!

Comment: My version of MegaRAID doesn't like the `Scan` option.  This worked: `/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -CfgForeign -Clear -a0`.  Use `-aALL` for all adapters.

Comment: Thanks for this! Incidentally, the storcli version of this error message is "physical disk does not have appropriate attributes", and the form of this command is `storcli /c0 /fall delete` (or `/call` for all controllers).

Answer (score 4):

I'm embarrased to say that I had this problem today and lost about 2 hours of my life for not looking at the drives before trying to replace them.

The key to the issue here is **Exit Code: 0x26**, which means "Unable to use SATA(SAS) drive to replace SAS(SATA)".

The  FUJITSU MBD2147RC are SAS drives and the SEAGATE ST9300603SS are SATA drives. You cannot make a hardware RAID with drives that use different protocols. It's either all SAS or all SATA. If you need to mix them you can make a software RAID.

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/MegaCLI_Error_Messages has a list of the error codes of MegaCli.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and for me it required to do:

`megacli -PDMakeGood -PhysDrv '[64:6]' -Force -a0`

After that I could create the raid with the CfgLdAdd command.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I faced with same problem time ago. If it's still relevant you should:

- Check if you have **Unconfigured(good)** drive:

  ```
  root@sto:~# sudo python scripts/megaraid_status.py
  c0uXpY  | SSD  | FECA075B010803000281Patriot Blast SAFM11.0 | 446.1 Gb | Unconfigured(good), Spun Up | 6.0Gb/s  | N/A  | [252:3]  | 0
  ```
- Check foreign configuration:

  ```
  root@sto# megacli -CfgForeign -Scan -aall
  There are 1 foreign configuration(s) on controller 0.
  Exit Code: 0x00
  ```
- Clear it:

  ```
  root@sto# megacli -CfgForeign -Clear -aall
  Foreign configuration 0 is cleared on controller 0.
  Exit Code: 0x00
  ```

Source: http://sysadm.pp.ua/linux/monitoring-systems/megaraid-assembling-raid6.html